# How can I add Tabs & Fragment dynamically

Tags: android, tabs, android-design-library, android-tablayout, androiddesignsupport

How can I add Tabs & Fragment dynamically ?

My code :

```
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    adapter.addFrag(new TabFragment(), "Tab"+i);
     }
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Tab Fragment

```
public class TabFragment extends ListFragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activty_listview,container, false);
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}
```

}

Suppose my tab names are "Tab1, Tab2, Tab3" 
How can I add tabs dynamically according to the Array if I get above and how to tab fragment know which tab selected.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:layout_height="48dp" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>

Activity:


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initViews();
    }

    int icons[] = {R.mipmap.createuser, R.mipmap.ico_password, R.mipmap.gplus, R.mipmap.fb};
    int colors[] = {Color.YELLOW, Color.CYAN, Color.LTGRAY, Color.CYAN};

    void initViews() {
        TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Fragment1(),new Fragment2(),new Fragment3(),new Fragment4()));

        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(pager);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.tabs,null,false);

            TextView title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.layout);
            ImageView icon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            title.setText("Tab" + i);
            layout.setBackgroundColor(colors[i]);
            icon.setImageResource(icons[i]);
           // tabs.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(view);
        tabs.getTabAt(i).setIcon(icons[i]);

        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

Adapter:

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by rohit.h on 12/21/2015.
 */
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    String titles[] = {"Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3", "Tab4"};
    private final List<Fragment> fragments;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles[position];
    }
}
```

Comment: i am create same fragment for all tabs how can i diffrentiate

Comment: uneed to create a list of both fragment and titles for tab  at runtime and notify the adapter it can automatically refresh it or plz display your code

Comment: i have update my code please let me know how to get value ex: if i select tab1, how can i get value in my fragment.

Comment: Actually you need to create objects of fragments in Actvity from where you can set pageradapter

Comment: You need to add listeners on pager and using the objects you get the values

Answer (score 0):

```
 mTabLayout = (TabLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText(getResources().getString(R.string.tab1)));
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText(getResources().getString(R.string.tab2)));
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText(getResources().getString(R.string.tab3)));
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText(getResources().getString(R.string.tab4)));
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText(getResources().getString(R.string.tab5)));
        mTabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        mTabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);

        mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), mTabLayout.getTabCount());

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabLayout));
```

you can refer [this](http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/) link

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution (but not the best/perfect one) would be to add the fragments to adapter and set the tablayout and adapter to viewpager again at runtime. Will not be clean / might be jerky but will definitely work.

EDIT::
There's a method in FragmentPagerAdapter which is set to viewpager and tablayout as well : notifyDataSetChanged(). Use this method after inserting and removing fragments from pager adapter. I tried this for inserting it works. Should definitely work for removing as well.

Comment: A very simple answer. I think you should try to add some example code.